# Issue regarding getting a field from a structure as a array of string pointers and saving them in an instance variable of an array of string pointers

Tags: c

So i have a struct that i define as followed

```
struct pastCommand
{

    int numberOfCommand;
    char *command;
    char *commandslist[10];
    int commandlistLength;
};
```

Ive written a function that can print a structure in the way i want

```
    void printHistoryElement(struct pastCommand *currentHistory)
{


    if(currentHistory==NULL)
    {


    }
    else
    {
    int myLength=currentHistory->commandlistLength;
    int numberCommand=currentHistory->numberOfCommand;
    char *myCommand=currentHistory->command;
    char *currentList[] = currentHistory->commandslist;
    printf("Commands #%d: %s\n",numberCommand, *myCommand);
    for(int i=0; i<myLength; i++)
    {

        printf("arg[%d] :%s\n",i,currentList[i]);


    }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

When i get an issue on this line

```
char *currentList[] = currentHistory->commandslist;
```

With the error saying error: array initializer must be an initializer list

Im not sure exactly what the issue is, they are the same type, an array of pointers to strings, however i cant put my finger on the issue. Some insight on this problem would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty square bracket `[]` syntax in declarations is for defining arrays with the size defined by the array initializer. In your code, however, you are simply pointing to some existing array, so you could do it with a pointer. Since your array is an array of pointers, you need a pointer to pointer, like this:

```
char **currentList = currentHistory->commandslist;
```

The rest of your code remains the same.

Note that although this will work, it is entirely unnecessary to store a pointer to the array in a local variable. You can rewrite your code without the local, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<myLength; i++)
{
    printf("arg[%d] :%s\n", i, currentHistory->commandslist[i]);
}
```